# communicating between views in Backbone + RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am using Backbone + RequireJS to develop an app. When a user links to the web page, he can select one of the products (render the first view). After the selection, the next page should render the second view according to the selection. That is, as the second view is rendered, it should know the selection by the user in the first view. The code looks like this:

for viewA.js:

```
define(['jquery','backbone','underscore','text!template/ViewA.html'],function($,Backbone,_,templateA) {
        // render for view A
        // switch to view B after user do selection
    });
```

for viewB.js:

```
define(['jquery','backbone','underscore','text!template/ViewA.html'],function($,Backbone,_,templateA) {
        // render for view B according to selection in view A            
    });
```

Is there any formal method to achieve this other than using a global variable?
I've done some study and it seems that one solution is to use an event aggregator to trigger in the first view and listen to the second view. However, in the current scenario, the second view is not instantiated (as shown in viewA.js in which viewB is not included yet) when the user selection event is triggered in the first view. And it looks strange to include viewB in viewA.js just for the event aggregator to work properly...

Comment: There should be a parent view for viewA and viewB. There should also be a main display model that would control which view to display. The parent view would listen to changes for that display model. The other two views should have there own model. When the user makes a selection for viewB, update the main display model with viewB's model. And the parent view would trigger the listener function where you can update the view.

Comment: Your 'products' route/URL should contain the id of the product as a parameter. This is the standard, REST-ful way: http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes